# How to draw a figure on mouse click in qtapplication

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm new to Pyqt5 and writing applications with it in Python so forgive me if this is a very simple question but I'm having trouble drawing ellipses in my program. I want to draw one by wherever a click occurs. Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        
        
        
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        
        
        # p.setTransform(transform)

        self.button = QPushButton("Draw")
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setGeometry(0, 0, 100, 30)
        
        
        self.scene.addWidget(self.button)
        
        
        # self.setMouseTracking(True)
        width, height = 1000, 1000
        self.setFixedSize(width, height);
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, width, height);
        self.fitInView(0, 0, width, height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio);  
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.show()
       
        
            
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):


        if self.button.isChecked():
            x = event.x()
            y = event.y()
            print(x, y)
            
            ellipse = QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, 50, 20)
            self.scene.addItem(ellipse)
```

The issue I'm having is I think the mousePressEvent function isn't allowing me to click on my button to enable drawing but the part I'm really not sure about is what is going on in the mousePressEvent. It seems as though it's getting the (x, y) coordinates within the QGraphicsView object but my ellipses are getting drawn in strange spots far away from wherever is clicked in my application when it's open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not override the mousePressEvent as you remove the default behavior such as sending the event to the button. On the other hand you have to convert the coordinates of the view to the coordinates of the scene.

```py
self.proxy_widget = self.scene.addWidget(self.button)
```

```py
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super().mousePressEvent(event)
    vp = event.pos()
    if self.proxy_widget in self.items(vp):
        return
    if self.button.isChecked():
        ellipse = QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 50, 20)
        self.scene.addItem(ellipse)
        sp = self.mapToScene(vp)
        ellipse.setPos(sp)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly now. So was I incorrectly using the QGraphicsScene().mousePressEvent()? And does the first "if" statement for the self.proxy_widget just ensure that the button is treated separately from the rest of the view?

Comment: @MikeP. No: you were not calling the *default behavior* of `mousePressEvent` on the view: by default (not overriding its function, or not calling it by `super()`) the *view* creates a special "graphics scene mouse event" that is sent to the scene, which, in turn, calls its own `mousePressEvent` with that special event, and that eventually sends that same event to the items that exist in under that scene position; each item might then react to the event, including "proxy" widgets. Since you didn't call the base implementation, the button never received any mouse event.

Comment: @musicamante. Thanks for the explanation, I think that makes sense now. I was confused originally with how the mousePressEvent was working here

Comment: eyllanesc you didn't read your email? trying to get in contact with you!